# Bash completion command

Tags: bash, bash-completion

in my function I have

```
# Tab completion
if [ "$1" = "--complete" ]; then
    shift
    # Commands
    for line in $(compgen -ac "notes_$1" | sed 's/^notes_//'); do
        echo $line
    done
    # Notes
    for line in $(cd $NOTES_DIR; ls $1* 2>/dev/null); do
        echo $line
    done
    return
```

this should list all commands which start with notes_ and all files in some directory, and it does when called like `notes --complete`. However, when i try to use tab completion

```
complete -C 'notes --complete "$COMP_LINE"' notes
```

it shows only the files not the commands?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
echo "--$1--"
```

after

```
shift
```

The problem is that in

```
compgen -ac "notes_$1"
```

the contents are not what you expect

I guess *$1* has the value *notes* when you do

```
$ notes <TAB>
```

And there is no notes_notes* alias or command in your *PATH*

Check that adding an alias notes_notesWHATEVER and trying again autocompletion